# asp.net app calling service says its not initialized?

Tags: asp.net, linux, mono

So this code runs in an asp.net app on Linux. The code calls one of my services. (WCF doesn't work on mono currently, that is why I'm using asmx). This code works AS INTENDED when running from Windows (while debugging).  As soon as I deploy to Linux, it stops working.  I'm definitely baffled. I've tested the service thoroughly and the service is fine.

Here is the code producing an error:    (NewVisitor is a void function taking 3 strings in)

```
//This does not work.
try
 {
     var client = new Service1SoapClient();
     var results = client.NewVisitor(Request.UserHostAddress, Request.UrlReferrer == null ? String.Empty : Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(), Request.UserAgent);
     Logger.Debug("Result of client: " + results);
 }
```

Here is the error generated: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Here is the code that works perfectly:

```
 //This works (from the service)
 [WebMethod(CacheDuration = _cacheTime, Description = "Returns a List of Dates", MessageName = "GetDates")]
 public List<MySqlDateTime> GetDates()
 {
     return db.GetDates();
 }

 //Here is the code for the method above
 var client = new Service1Soap12Client();
 var dbDates = client.GetDates();
```

I'd love to figure out why it is saying that the object is not set.

Methods tried:

1. new soap client.
2. new soap client with binding and endpoint address specified
3. Used channel factory to create and open the channel.

If more info is needed I can give more. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Does the top of the NullReferenceException stacktrace point to your code? And exactly which object is null?

Comment: var client = new Service1SoapClient();  is the object that is null. Which to me makes no sense since I use the same line of code in a different form and that works fine.

Comment: The 'client' variable can't be null (it would be a violation of the C# spec). What is probably happening is that some code in GetDates is throwing the NullReferenceException - seeing the complete stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: Here is a link for the complete stacktrace. http://pastebin.com/fwPaYYYF I know this has nothing to do with the GetDates function due to this error log: Call_Service Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: It looks like a bug in mono. You should file a bug (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with a reproducible test case so it can be fixed (and possibly find a workaround you can use).

Comment: if you can mark this as the answer, it would be appreciated.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug in mono. You should [file a bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with a reproducible test case so it can be fixed (and possibly find a workaround you can use).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't have Linux to test it but I'd suggest you put the client variable in an using() statement:

```
using(var client = new Service1SoapClient())
{
     var results = client.NewVisitor(Request.UserHostAddress, Request.UrlReferrer == null ? 
                       String.Empty : Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(), Request.UserAgent);
     Logger.Debug("Result of client: " + results);
}
```

I hope it helps.

RC.

Comment: Tested from Linux and still no dice.